# Biochemistry applications for touchscreens: dragging proteins, and making them coast, by each other

Tags: windows, android, web, scientific-computing, research

I am looking for scientific biochemistry software for personal computers, such as Windows 11.

Both would involve the touchscreen, and would be geared towards biochemical or biological it medical, applications.

They could be used, by students.

If the software, got, complex (and usable, it could be used by bioresearchers in bioinformatics, as well).

In the software, you could model, molecule composition and interactions, by dragging, and, pushing, molecules, against each other, with the finger.

You could do the same thing within an organic chemistry biological animal or vegetable cell.

You, can make, proteins, nutrients, and other micro-molecules, coast, by each other (by pointing on them, and, dragging them, with the finger (through, cell walls, by the nucleus, and onto each other).

What would be better, is if you can also do this via a web interface, in an Android phone (but, on a PC, you would have more space, and more screen estate, and ťhe experience would be better.

A, computer, with finger touchscreen and drag (drop?), would really do.

Thank you.

Where can I find such software (or, anything similar, along these lines)?

Thank you.